# Intersection Observer making text immediately appear on screen and not fade into screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using intersection observer to create lazy loading text and images. For this question, I just asking about the text. The text, when in sight, goes from 0 opacity to 1 opacity. It just appears on screen when 50% of is it the document's viewport. The intersection observer is supposed to do this, but by making it fade when 50% of the text comes into the viewport. It's almost like there is no (transform: opacity 3s). Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mynerve&family=Nunito&family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Trelp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class='header'>
        <img src="images/bgImage.png" alt="Not Loading..." class="bgImage">
        <div class="bgImageScreen"></div>
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Not Loading..." class="logo" width="150px" height="40px">
        <div class="title">Build Your<br>Business</div>
        <div class="subText">Work with experts to create and grow<br>your business.</div>
        <a href=""><div class="learnMore"><h3>Learn More</h3></div></a>
        </header>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="businessTitle hidden">80% of Business Fail</div>
            <div class="businessText hidden">Start up businesses fail all around the world. 
                The majority of times, the business lacks funding, market research, and is poorly planned. 
                Failure could also stem from the founder having unrealistic expectations about the future of the Business. 
                This has become an issue, for businesses drive economic growth.
                Here at Trelp, we've addressed this issue, and have found a perfect solution. 
                </div>
            <img src="images/business.png" alt="Not Loading..." class="businessImage"> 
        </section>
    </div>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

:root {
    --black: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    perspective: 10px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.bgImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

.bgImageScreen {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 102%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 102%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.626), black);
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: -1;
}

.logo {
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1470px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.title {
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 90px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1400px;
    left: 120px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.subText {
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1400px;
    left: 120px;
}

.learnMore {
    width: 180px;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1400px;
    left: 120px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 3px solid var(--white);
    background-color: var(--white);
    color: var(--black);
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.learnMore:hover {
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150vh;
    background: var(--black);
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 27px;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: opacity 3s;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
}

.businessImage {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 750px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.businessTitle {
    color: green;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 500px;
}

.businessText {
    color: green;
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

Javascript

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.5) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show')
        } else {
            entry.target.classList.remove('show')
        }
    }) 
}, {threshold: [0.5]})

const hiddenElement = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')
hiddenElement.forEach(el => observer.observe(el))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have meant to apply `transition: opacity 3s` instead of `transform: opacity 3s` in the `.hidden` rule:

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.5) {
      entry.target.classList.add('show')
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove('show')
    }
  })
}, {
  threshold: [0.5]
})

const hiddenElement = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')
hiddenElement.forEach(el => observer.observe(el))
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

:root {
  --black: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.container {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  perspective: 10px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.bgImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

.bgImageScreen {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 102%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 102%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.626), black);
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}

.logo {
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1470px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.title {
  color: var(--white);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 90px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1400px;
  left: 120px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.subText {
  color: var(--white);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1400px;
  left: 120px;
}

.learnMore {
  width: 180px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1400px;
  left: 120px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px solid var(--white);
  background-color: var(--white);
  color: var(--black);
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.learnMore:hover {
  color: var(--white);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
  background: var(--black);
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 27px;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.businessImage {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 400px;
  left: 750px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.businessTitle {
  color: green;
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 500px;
}

.businessText {
  color: green;
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mynerve&family=Nunito&family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Trelp</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class='header'>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1600/900" alt="Not Loading..." class="bgImage">
      <div class="bgImageScreen"></div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/40" alt="Not Loading..." class="logo" width="150px" height="40px">
      <div class="title">Build Your<br>Business</div>
      <div class="subText">Work with experts to create and grow<br>your business.</div>
      <a href="">
        <div class="learnMore">
          <h3>Learn More</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </header>
    <section class="section">
      <div class="businessTitle hidden">80% of Business Fail</div>
      <div class="businessText hidden">Start up businesses fail all around the world. The majority of times, the business lacks funding, market research, and is poorly planned. Failure could also stem from the founder having unrealistic expectations about the future of the Business.
        This has become an issue, for businesses drive economic growth. Here at Trelp, we've addressed this issue, and have found a perfect solution.
      </div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1600/900" alt="Not Loading..." class="businessImage">
    </section>
  </div>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```